# Issue getting selected radio value on dynamically built radios

Tags: jquery, html

I am dynamically building radio buttons (recipeItem's) from data returned with JSON. I then append the recipeItem to the recipe cage. This part works perfectly.

I also add a div to the vendorCage to assign vendors to the recipeItem. So far so good. No issue.

I have a button that adds a vendor to the selected recipe's vendorCage. This is where the issue is. The first time I select a recipeItem and then click the button, it works as expected. It adds a vendor to the proper vendorCage. The issue is every time after that, when I check the recipe, it's always the first recipe's value.

So my question is: Am I having this problem because I am creating these on the fly or am I just simply missing something?

**The code for getting the selected recipeItem**

```
var recipe = $('input:radio[name="recipe_item"]').val();
```

**The code used to build the recipeItems**

```
var $recipeItemsCage = $('#recipe-items-cage');
$.each(response.data['items'], function (key, value) {
    var recipeItem = $("<label />", {
        html: $('<input />', {
            type: "radio",
            name: "recipe_item",
            class: "recipe-item",
            value: key
        })
    }).append(key + ' - ' + value);
    $recipeItemsCage.append($('<li></li>', {
        html: recipeItem
    }));
    // Add recipe item vendor cage
    $vendorCage.append(
    $('<div></div>', {
        id: 'recipe-vendors-cage-' + key
    }));
});
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a js-fiddle so one can get a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It seems I found my answer. I just have to add :checked to the end of the selector for the recipe. Yeah, js-fiddle would have been a good idea, I'll keep that in mind for next time I have a question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to do this:

```
var recipe = $('input:radio[name="recipe_item"]:checked').val();
```